# Java-Two separate instances of an object both being modified at the same time

Tags: java, eclipse, class, oop

So I'm trying to do my homework for class but am running into a weird issue. Whenever I modify a variable *size* in one instance of my class *Queue*, it modifies the size variable of the other instance of the class as well. For example

```
    Queue takeoffQueue=new Queue();
    Queue landingQueue=new Queue();

    System.out.println("TakeoffSize "+takeoffQueue.size);
    System.out.println("LandingSize "+landingQueue.size);

    takeoffQueue.size++;

    System.out.println("TakeoffSize "+takeoffQueue.size);
    System.out.println("LandingSize "+landingQueue.size);
```

Will print out:

TakeoffSize 0

LandingSize 0

TakeoffSize 1

LandingSize1

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: where is your Queue class?

Comment: This can happen if the `size` variable is `static`

Comment: dont use static variable in queue

Comment: make `size` as instance variable

Comment: But in my Queue class I need to modify size as I add and remove nodes, so in my understanding it needs to be static. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: A static variable is shared between instances. To be more specific, it is independent of instances. You do not want to make it static. It definitely sounds like you want is to make `size` and instance variable, like people have been saying.

Comment: Ok, I see. I guess I understand static a lot better now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can look at it like this (simplified):

Static variables are class-wide. If you set a value to static variable, that means it holds for all the past, present and current instances of that class.

On the other hand, instance variables define a property that is bound to one specific instance of a problem.

Again, in layman terms:

```
public class Person {
    public static int NUMBER_OF_EYES = 2;
    public int numberOfHealthyEyes;
}
```

It is reasonable to assume that all human beings have 2 eyes, and that is a feature shared by all humans. However, individual people (instances of Person) may have different number of healthy eyes. Some may be blind, so that number will be 0 for them, and so on.

Long story short, when you need to describe a part of an inner state of an instance of a class, you use instance variables. When you want to describe a shared property, you can use static ones.

Here's the link tot the Oracle page about variables in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am late but just want to explain difference between `static` and `non-static` accoding to my view.

I think(as you dint mention the declaration of size variable) the `size` variable you declared is a static variable which causes same value for all objects of that class in the memory.

**Static:**

So when you do

```
static int size=0;
Queue takeoffQueue=new Queue();
Queue landingQueue=new Queue();
```

what happens in memory

[image: Static varible common memory]

The `size` varible is shared among all the objets of that class so if you change value of `size` for any object it would be affected to other objects also.

**Non-Static:**

If you have done

```
    int size=0;
    Queue takeoffQueue=new Queue();
    Queue landingQueue=new Queue();
```

The memory created would be something like

[image: Non-static varible each variable have its own space]

In this case each object of that class would have their own `size` varible so if you increase `size` variable of one object it  would not affect size variable of other.

You can choose what type of variable you want For ex. if you have a `Student` class of a same school then the variable `schoolName` would be static because the school name would be same for all student(objects) the advantage is that it saves memory instead of creating `schoolName` as non-static for each object.And on the other way variable `studentName` would be non-static because it would be different for eact object.